# Cocoa preg_split equivalent

Tags: regex, cocoa, preg-split

I'm using `preg_split` to split a string based on a regular expression in PHP, using the following code:

```
$array = preg_split("~(?<!\*),~", $string);
```

What is the equivalent in Cocoa?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2062338/127880

Comment: Looks like you'll have to check out the various 3rd party RegEx libraries for Cocoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up writing my own method using `NSRegularExpression`

```
+ (NSArray *)preg_split:(NSString *)expression withSubject:(NSString *)subject {

    NSRegularExpression *exp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *matches = [exp matchesInString:subject options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subject length])];
    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        [results addObject:[subject substringWithRange:[match range]]];
    }

    return results;

}
```